# How do some banks have such short account numbers?

Tags: banking

Mitsui Sumitomo and Lloyds Bank (among others, I presume) use 7 digit bank account numbers. It seems that if they have more that 9,999,999 customers, they wouldn't be able to route transactions to the new ones.

While I couldn't find an exact figure for the number of customers [this page](https://www.lloydsbankinggroup.com/media/media-kit/faqs/lloyds-banking-group-fast-facts/) indicates that Lloyds Banking Group (of which Lloyds Bank is the foremost member) has 30 million customers. Furthermore, Mitsui Sumitomo is, AFAIK, the largest bank in Japan. Japan has a population of 120 million, meaning that if Mitsui Sumitomo has a 10% market share it would have more customers than account numbers.

How do they get around this?

Comment: Multiple SWIFT codes?  (In the US, I know that Chase Bank has a different routing number for each state it has branches. New York State even has **two** routing numbers.)

Comment: @RonJohn Looking at [Japan Bank Directory](https://www.japanbankdirectory.com/by-letter/m/mitsui-sumitomo/), it looks like at least Mitsui Sumitomo uses the same SWIFT code for all branches. I know I do have to provide my branch number to log in to online banking though, so maybe that's along the right lines.

Comment: Do they perhaps just omit the leading zeros?  E.g. when I log in to my credit union's web site, my account number is 4 digits.  On checks and other places (like IRS electronic payments) those 4 digits must have 12 leading zeros.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about personal finance and money issue that the OP is facing.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Which site should this be posted on?

Answer (score 4):

In the UK, Lloyds use Sort Codes AND account numbers to identify a specific bank account.

Lloyds have the Sort Code Range of 30-00-00 to 39-99-99 available, so they have enough codes for everyone on the planet to have 10 accounts.